# Meteor Autoform "Method '/insert' not found [404]"

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-autoform

I've got this strange behavior that the autoform package throws a 404 when i try to submit my form.

I hope i got the install instructions and the basic demo right.
I try to provide the needed files. For starters the Schema, Html and the JS File.

Schema (imports/api/footballs/footballs.js):

```
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';
import SimpleSchema from 'simpl-schema';


SimpleSchema.extendOptions(['autoform']);

export const Footballs = new Mongo.Collection('footballs');

Footballs.attachSchema (new SimpleSchema({
  playerone: {
    type: String,
    label: 'Player One',
    max: 255,
  },
  playertwo: {
    type: String,
    label: 'Player Two',
    max: 255,
  },
  gamedate: {
    type: Date,
    label: 'Game Data',
    autoValue: function autoValueCreatedAt() {
      return new Date();
    },
    autoform: {
      type: 'hidden'
    },
  },
},
{tracker: Tracker}));
```

HTML (imports/ui/pages/stadium.html)

```
<template name="stadium">
  <h1>Lets play kicker!</h1>
  {{> quickForm collection=footballCollection id="insertFootballsForm" type="insert" class="newFootballForm"}}
</template>
```

JS (imports/ui/pages/stadium.js)

```
import {Footballs} from '../../api/footballs/footballs.js';
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';

import './stadium.html';

Template.stadium.helpers({
  footballCollection(){
    return Footballs;
  },
});
```

Comment: Did you define the collection on the server as well?

Comment: I'm not quite sure where I should have done it. I thought the Js File (last example) would be the server side definition of the collection.

Comment: You need to have the collection imported from somewhere on the server. It is not clear from your posted code where exactly each piece of code is located and where it is imported from. Make sure that the file that defines the collection (or another collection definition file specific for the server) is imported from the server.

Comment: Added the path to the files. I tried to stick to the [guide](https://guide.meteor.com/structure.html#example-app-structure) Shall I register the collection somewhere in the startup folder?

Comment: You can try and trace your imports chain from the server entry point. In the guide, the can be similar to the following: something in the `/server` directory imports `/imports/startup/server/index.js` -> `/imports/api/api.js` -> `imports/api/footballs/footballs.js`. An easy way to quickly check if the file is imported is to add a `console.log` call and see if what you logged appears on server startup.

Comment: I put a [console.log] into [footballCollection()] and at the end of the schema file. Both log the same object. So I would assume that works correct.

Comment: on the server (i.e, command line terminal)?

Comment: Browser console.

Comment: As I mentioned several times before, check if the file is imported on your *server*. Printing stuff in the browser console and deducing that everything is ok will lead us nowhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @MasterAM patience, here is the solution. The collection was indeed not present on the server side and therefore had to be imported. Which didn't happend.

Server/main.js

```
import '../imports/startup/server';
```

(imports/startup/server/index.js)

```
import { Footballs } from '../../api/footballs/footballs.js';
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check if you're using the 'insecure' module, with

```
meteor list
```

if it's not on the list, you can

```
meteor add insecure
```

or, add this after the definition of the collection.

```
Footballs.allow( { 
    insert() { 
        /*here goes the logic to determine if someone is allowed*/
        return true; 
    },
    update() { return true; },
    remove() { return true; }
} )
```

btw, if you're using the collection directly, you could use this on the template instead of writing a helper:

```
{{> quickForm collection="footballs" id="insertFootballsForm" type="insert" class="newFootballForm"}}
```

Comment: Adding `insecure` is generally a bad idea and in this case I assume will not solve the issue.

Comment: The app ist still [insecure], and the adding the collection directly results into the following error "Exception in template helper: Error: Footballs is not in the window scope"

Comment: Autoform package does not need `insecure` nor allow/deny on the Client.